# Register Account(window) Rejection when value is on database (MySQL)

Tags: python, mysql, database, pyqt5

```
def Register(self):
    QMessageBox.about(self,"Successfully Saved Data",'saved')
    username = self.lineEdit.text()
    pwd = self.lineEdit_2.text()
    cursor = self.connek.cursor()
    into_data = 'insert into login(username,passwrd) values(%s,%s);'
    db_column = (username , pwd)
    cursor.execute(into_data, db_column)
    self.connek.commit()
    cursor1 = self.connek.cursor()
    cursor1.execute('select username, passwrd from login;')
    x = cursor1.fetchall()
    print(x)
    login.show()
    reg.hide()
    cursor.close()
```

Hi guys I'm new to Pyqt5 and MySql
my sole goal is to put a rejection message if there is an existing account in the database 
however I don't have enough knowledge to do it so.
will you help me please?
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If username isn't a unique or primary key of the `login` table, make it one.

```
ALTER TABLE login ADD UNIQUE KEY (username);
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE login ADD PRIMARY KEY (username);
```

When you attempt an insert, look at the result for the duplicate key error. In that case a user already exists.

Comment: Personally, I think username as a primary key is a poor idea

Comment: Thinking about it, you're right. There's probably only the case where its a login table that isn't linked to anything that make an ok/not terrible case for a PK being username. Once you start linking to anything you'd rather have an integer primary key for key space efficiency and to allow usernames to change.

Comment: Hello sir! regarding about that that I already made the username a unique key, however, when I click the push button intended for registering the account, the GUI crashes with no error.

Comment: You haven't caught the duplicate key exception in the Register function. Check the logs on the console.