# Checking database for pre-existing email

Tags: php, mysql

So in my database I am having trouble with the syntax for searching my database and getting my program to do what I want. I want to see if the email entered already exists in the database, and if it does I want to stop the signup process and tell the user to use a different email to sign up. This is the code im having trouble with

```
//check to see if email is available
        $check_email = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email = $email";
        if(mysqli_query($db, $check_email) >= 1){
            echo 'Email in use, try another email';
        }else{
            //continue to insert data into users table
        }
```

I know it is connected to the database because I've already inserted users in the table like this before I added this filter to find emails which already exist. What logic should I use to make the above code snippet do what I am aiming for?

Comment: You need to check for query failures, because your query is almost certainly failing, because `$email` probably doesn't have quotation marks around it. You should not fix it by simply adding quotation marks, but by researching parameterized queries that will save you from SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: First learn to use parameterized queries.

Comment: That is several levels of not-working code, but if you fixed all the bad syntax in it it would do what you're asking. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display/21429652?r=SearchResults&s=1|251.8590#21429652 You should also also use a prepared statement instead of asking for SQL injection like that. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Also rather than checking for the email, create a UNIQUE INDEX on email [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60629682/register-accountwindow-rejection-when-value-is-on-database-mysql/60629717#60629717) and when INSERTing detect the Duplicate key exception. Doing a check up front is subject to race conditions where another user (or same user inadvertently) could insert between you checking and the entry being there.